# How to insert figures with two column break

Tags: floats, two-column, ieeetran

I need to insert some plots with one column in a two column style. How can break it. I use the IEEE journal paper style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\begin{figure*}` is a figure that spans both columns.